# MVC razor how do align text-box's?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using MVC 4 and razor and have placed label for and textbox for in the view. All the textbox's are sitting right against the labels, how do i move them a tab space away or so and keep them aligned?

Razor:

```
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date)
    <br/>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.QuoteNumber)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.QuoteNumber)
    <br/>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ClaimNumber)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ClaimNumber)
    <br/>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MotorBodyRepairer)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MotorBodyRepairer)
    <br/>
```

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This is simple css styling, nothing to do with MVC nor with Razor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Model**

Add display attributes:

```
        [Display(Name="Date")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Quote Number")]
        public string QuoteNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Claim Number")]
        public string ClaimNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Motor Body Repairer")]
        public string MotorBodyRepairer { get; set; }
```

**View**

Use an editor for template

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m)
```

**CSS**

Add this to your style sheet, changing the values to suite.

```
.editor-label > label
{
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}
```

**Screen grab**

[image]

**Update**

Replace this:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">

    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date)
    <br/>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.QuoteNumber)
    <br/>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ClaimNumber)
    <br/>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MotorBodyRepairer)
    <br/>

</div>
```

With this:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
</div>
```

Comment: I have all my text box's in a line but no labels are show? also with editorFor(m => m) should it be that or (m => m.date) ect

Comment: @Pomster You add the EditorFor to your entire model object and you will need to add the Display name as detailed above to your model too and it will display as above.

Comment: I have done as you have asked but there is no display name showing?

Comment: No editor-label is being created?

Comment: Was i correct to add using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

Comment: @Pomster Yes, you were correct. Please could you post your model and I can take a look?

Comment: Cool, the names are back its not displaying correctly just yet though but i can fix that. One problem i am having is, i have 8 feilds and i want 4 on the left and 4 on the right with @Html.EditorFor(m => m) it displays them all. how do i spit it?

Comment: Please see edit 2 this is what has happened after the edit

Comment: @Pomster Hi, the question has became a moving target. I would create another one and post your outputted html. You will get an answer quicker that way.

Comment: @Pomster No problem, good luck with the rest. :)